# Regex in C# for password

Tags: c#, regex

I have regex for validating user passwords to contain:

> - atleast 8 alpha numberic characters
> - 1 uppercase letter
> - 1 lowercase letter
> - 1 digit
>
> Allowed special charaters !@#$%*.~

I am using the following regex:

```
(?=(.*\w){8,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){1,})(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[0-9]){1,})(?=(.*[!@#$%*.~]))
```

This however does not prevent the user from entering other special characters
such as <,> , &.

How do I can restrict the allowed number of special characters?

Comment: A regular expression is probably not a good way to check for this.  Also, restricting the special characters allowed doesn't do anything but make adding them meaningless, since the password strength is a function of the alphabet size.  The fact that you're restricting them almost implies you're storing them in a database in plain text, but I'm sure you're not doing that.

Comment: Let them enter anything, don't restrict the set of characters.  I absolutely ***HATE*** when I can't use a stronger password because  a `-` isn't allowed.  Why shouldn't I be allowed to use `'"-()[]&<>^_+=` etc in my password?

Comment: Agreed - you should validate that they have met a minimum standard for password strength, but not limit the strength of the passwords that they can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%*.~]{8,}$
```

The anchoring (`^` and `$`) is important, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

A *single* regex to validate *everything* will ultimately look like line noise.

Instead I suggest:

- Use simple String functions to test length
- Use Regex to test for character inclusion and validity